# Google tag manager publishing doesn't work

Tags: google-tag-manager

Over than week ago publishing on google tag manager broke for my container. It always returns unknown error.

This error appears only when I am trying to add some tags, triggers or variables to workspace.

If I try to publish workspace with some deleted entities it works fine.

[Screenshot with an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0rUu.png)

Comment: You need to provide more information. What tags, triggers, and variables are in there?

Comment: There are 177 tags, 253 triggers and 55 variables. Now I try to add new built-in variable. But it doesn't work with new tags or triggers either